# C Converting 4 digit numbers to binary

Tags: c, recursion, binary

I want to print the binary equivalent of the numbers from a file in a 20 bit field with spaces after every 4 bits but when the number exceeds 1024 (I've tested this), it no longer outputs in binary but in a base I don't know (i.e. 1234 = 0000 0014 1006 5408)

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
long convertToBinary(long);

int main()
{
    char binNum[20]; //binary number char array
    int i;
    long b, decNum; //b is output binary number, decNum is each input number from file
    FILE *filePtr;
    filePtr = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    while (!feof(filePtr))
    {
        fscanf(filePtr, "%li", &decNum);
        if (decNum < 0  || decNum > 65535)
        {
            printf("Error, %5li is out of range.\n", decNum);
            continue;
        }
        b = convertToBinary(decNum); //function call for binary conversion

        i = 18;
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            if (i == 4 || i == 9 || i == 14)
            {
                binNum[i] = ' ';
            }
            else if (b != 0)
            {
                binNum[i] = b % 10 + '0';
                b /= 10;
            }
            else 
            {
                binNum[i] = '0';
            }
            i--;
        }
        binNum[19] = '.';
        printf("The binary representation of %5li is: ", decNum);
        for (i = 0; i<20; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", binNum[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

return 0;
}

//Recursion function
long convertToBinary(long number)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (number % 2 + 10 * convertToBinary(number / 2));
    }
}
```

The file `numbers.txt` has numbers like : 0 1 2 3 16 17 1234 5678 65535

Comment: Sorry, the numbers are 0 1 2 3 16 17 1234 5678 65535 and the output for 1234 should be `0000 0100 1101 0010` but is `0000 0014 2107 5418`

Comment: Your `convertToBinary()` function is overflowing the value that can be stored in a `long`.  Converting to a base 10 number so you can then print things is unusual.

Comment: In a binary digital computer, everything already is in binary form. Converting `long` to `long` does not make sense. As a sidenote: don't use recursion. This is only loved by computer science theory professors who don't write actual code.

Comment: @Olaf As a sidenote: Don't make blanket statements unless you back them up with something other than an ad hominem. That's only done by politicians. ...wait, dangit.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Oh, that statement is well funded on personal and communicated experience over ca. 30 years now. Maybe the "profs" was a bit too restrictive; there are other theoretical Cs ppl who think recursion is the Egg of Columbus. IRL, in C and other imperative languages it is often of littel to no use. In embedded programming some coding standards even explicit disallow them. Btw: this is not an argument, but a statement, so it can't be an "(argumentum) ad hominem". And it should be clear statements are **always** sujective; otherwise they were facts. (I might have missed the joke, though)

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure you know what the 'argumentum' in argumentum ad hominem means. It doesn't mean that two people are yelling at each other. It roughly means your reasoning for stating that something is true. So, yes, there was an argument: your argument that recursion is for people with no real-world experience. That's an ad hominem, because you're attacking the person, not the idea. After all, even an idiot can be factually correct; the point is to show why they're wrong. Hence why I asked for reasoning, not an appeal to authority or ad hominem.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: I very well know my latin and the meaning of that term. And it does not mean what you say, but attaching a person personally. I don't attack a specific person, but a class of persons. Not even theoretical CS profs per se, but a subset. You very well know that programming needs practicing, i.e. solving actual problems. Seem I hit a nerve, as you feel attacked personally. Until now, I assumed you _do_ practice quite a lot. (oh, and you have to read comment in the context of the domain, which is the C language here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `convertToBinary` function is producing a decimal-coded-binary (as opposed to a binary-coded-decimal) which uses a decimal digit per bit.

It looks like `long` has the same range as `int` on your system, i.e. 2<sup>31</sup>, which covers ten decimal digits. Once you get eleventh digit, you get an overflow.

Switching to `unsigned long long`, which has 64 bits, will fix the problem. However, this is sub-optimal: you would be better off writing a to-binary conversion that writes zeros and ones into an array of `char`s that you provide. You can do it recursively if you'd like, but an iterative solution will do just fine.

Note that the to-binary conversion does not need to insert spaces into `char` array. This can be done by your `main` function.